# addEventListener onchange dropdown selected value Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to run 2 functions according to the value selected by drop-down box.

Code:

```js
var activities = document.getElementById("stand");
activities.addEventListener("change", function() {

  if (activities.options[activities.selectedIndex].value == "stand1") {
    var footRight = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(.040, 0.55, 0.05), wallMaterial);
    partitionLeft.add(footRight);
    footRight.position.set(-0.12, -0.11, 2);
  } else {
    var footRight = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(.040, 0.55, 0.05), wallMaterial);
    partitionLeft.add(footRight);
    footRight.position.set(-4.12, -8.9, 6);
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="door-stand">
  <label>Select the stand type:</label>
  <select id="stand">
    <option class="stand1" value="stand1"> Stand 1 </option>
    <option class="stand2" value="stand2"> Stand 2 </option>
  </select>
</div>
```

The issue is even-though the values from the drop-down list keep changing, any of the above functions ain't trigger.

I tried to print something when the value changed in drop-down list; but, anything did not print at all.

---

There is a console error when I change the values in the drop-down. The console error pops up only when changing the values. That's why I haven't noticed. It says

> wallMaterial not defined

Comment: Have you checked the browser console for errors? If not then I suggest you do that.

Comment: @NewToJS Yeah, I actually did. There were no errors in the console.

Comment: Where is your JavaScript file linked into the HTML page? In the `<head>` or somewhere in `<body>`? If the latter, is it before or after your `<div id="door-stand">` element?

Comment: I tested without the Mesh functions, and it's having no problem. Probably something happens with Mesh functions, you should check the console.

Comment: FYI, `activities.options[activities.selectedIndex].value` can be simplified to just `activities.value`.

Comment: @Phil If that were the problem he would be getting an error about calling `addEventListener` on `null`.

Comment: Your code works here, so you must be doing something that you haven't shown us in your actual code.

Comment: @Barmar yes, I know but I don't completely believe that OP has no errors

Comment: @Barmar also, OP may have forgotten to link the JS file at all which would certainly create the symptoms observed :D

Comment: @Phil I certainly did include the JS file at the beginning of the index file. 

I just got what the issue is. There is a console error when I change the values in the drop-down. The console error pops up only when changing the values. That's why I haven't noticed. It says "wallMaterial not defined". I'll try to fix this issue. Thanks for your assistance!

Answer (score 7):

As you can see, after removing all the unnecessary code, this simple snippet works as expected:

```js
const activities = document.getElementById('stand');

activities.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  console.log(`e.target.value = ${ e.target.value }`);
  console.log(`activities.options[activities.selectedIndex].value = ${ activities.options[activities.selectedIndex].value }`);
});
```

```html
<select id="stand">
  <option class="stand1" value="stand1">Stand 1</option>
  <option class="stand2" value="stand2">Stand 2</option>
</select>
```

This means there might be something else wrong in your code:

- Maybe something is erroring out:

  ```js
  const activities = document.getElementById('stand');

  activities.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    console.log('Change START');
    
    activities.nonexistentFunction();  
    
    console.log('Change END');
  });
  ```

  ```html
  <select id="stand">
    <option class="stand1" value="stand1">Stand 1</option>
    <option class="stand2" value="stand2">Stand 2</option>
  </select>
  ```
- Maybe you have some other `change` listeners that are calling [`Event.stopImmediatePropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopImmediatePropagation):

  ```js
  const activities = document.getElementById('stand');

  activities.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    
    console.log('Change 1');
  });

  activities.addEventListener('change', (e) => {  
    console.log('Change 2');
  });
  ```

  ```html
  <select id="stand">
    <option class="stand1" value="stand1">Stand 1</option>
    <option class="stand2" value="stand2">Stand 2</option>
  </select>
  ```

Comment: So this post doesn't really solve the problem. I would recommend you post into the comments section since this hasn't fixed or explained the current issue.

Comment: @NewToJS According to the title and to _I tried to print something when the value changed in drop-down list; but, anything did not print at all_ it seems to me that this, at least, helps to point out what/where the cause of the problem might be and provide evidence of that through a really simple working example.

Comment: _"Maybe something is erroring out"_ <- OP says there are no errors (though I'm not entirely convinced). Nice example showing the effects of `stopImmediatePropagation()`

Comment: OP has confirmed there is an error so your first dot-point is right on the money

Answer (score 0):

You can use `this.value` to access the value of selected option inside your callback function:

```
   document.getElementById('stand').onChange = function(){  
        console.log(this.value);
    });
```